# For a studio, what kind of speaker system network should one opt for?

Tags: loudspeakers, amplifier, systems

For a Film Post Studio what kind of studio speaker network would be good , Active or Passive ? Why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say 'Film Post Studio' - do you mean an editing studio or a mix/dub stage? The requirements are related but very, very different

Active or passive is largely irrelevant, the main issue is for them being matched & correctly calibrated/set up. The advantage of active is that the manufacturer has already matched the speakers to the amps... whereas passive requires someone with knowledge to match & set them up - bi or tri-amped, crossovers etc....

Comment: Film Mix to be precise.